# CodeIgniter querying the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

If I place the `echo "h";` inside the if statement I get nothing returned. Also if I place a WHERE clause inside the SQL code and use that method, I also get nothing returned inside the foreach loop. Any ideas as to why this is happening? I only need the user that matches the current user logged in. And what the script's doing is looping through all the rows in the users table

```
public function dcr() {
    // pass all dashboard accesses through this function
    $username = $this->session->userdata("username");
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                    echo "h";
        if ($username == $row->username) {
                $data = array('firstname' => $row->firstname);
                $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there users in your table?

Comment: That depends on your users table, the wording of you WHERE, what $username is, etc. Posting them would help finding an answer.

Comment: I set the session wrong in my Ci controller. I got it working now.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby: Feel free to post your solution and mark it as accepted for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (have not tested), you don't need the if statement, just use function [get_where](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html), as the code will become cleaner and readable.

```
public function dcr() {
    // pass all dashboard accesses through this function
    $username = $this->session->userdata("username");
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('username' => $username));
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data = array('firstname' => $row->firstname);
        $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I need to start using those Ci methods. Somebody told me they have allot of security benefits.